# vb runtime with wpf application Netframwork

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm pretty new to development and in my company we use an old program written in VB which need vb6-runtime.

So to my question since the new pcs don't have any of the old files needed to run the old Program without installing all the necessary resources.
Is it possible to include the necessary files into a new WPF app from where I can start the old program and it will run?

As I'm writing I think its not because the path for the files are probably inside the old program so even with new references it wont find the files.

Sorry for this dump question I'm kind of new to development.

Comment: no. not in any way that's recommendable. either keep supporting the legacy-app, or - the much more sensible choice - rewrite it.

Comment: VB6 will be looking for dll on the computer you install the app to. You need to install those dependencies as well. But VB6 is very old now and I would (also) advise a re-write.